# OpenCV functions specifically built for uint8 datatype

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am using the cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback() function in Python to calculate the optical flow between two images and find the translation vector between the two displaced images. The images which I'm using have been generated by an atomic force microscope, which gives resolutions for each pixel value significantly greater than that which can be represented by the numbers from 0->255.

In fact, the pixel data at each point of the image is a 32-bit float between 0 and 1. I'd like to use this data with the optical flow function, rather than multiplying it all by 255 and rounding to the nearest integer, as this leads to a loss of information.

As far as I can tell, the OpenCV functions don't like data types that aren't uint8 (is this simply a limitation?). I'm wondering if there's some way around this? Perhaps there's a specifier which I'm unaware of, for example.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes, nobody implemented that because nobody needed it. -- your measurements aren't that accurate, even if they are that finely resolved. then, for optical flow, this is irrelevant. optical flow just needs some texture, which is there. just make sure to map the values so you use the dynamic range of uint8 well.

Comment: use DIS optical flow. it's modern, fast, dense, low on artefacts, and comes with OpenCV. if you compare with older algorithms (LK and TVL1), you'll prefer it.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Actually, the atomic force microscope is capable of imaging at length scales smaller than atoms. Both the precision and accuracy of my data is extremely high. I thought your comment was somewhat unnecessary, but I appreciate your other suggestion nonetheless.

Comment: I understand what an AFM is and that it operates in those length scales. don't dismiss what I say based on the assumption that I didn't understand that. I referred to dynamic range. does that make sense to you? can you make a case for requiring data given to **optical flow** to resolve steps of better than ~0.4% (1/256) of a full range along the "Z" axis ("intensity")?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz sure, I understand. The relationship between the resolution of your z-axis values and the accuracy of your linear drift predictions is not obvious, so it’s hard to say. However, I’m working with biological samples that experience macroscopic drift over not very long timescales. In the context of biological samples, you can only scan your sample with so much precision otherwise you may damage your sample or cause other unintended consequences. I simply want to use all the data available to me in order to get the most accurate predictions possible. Esp since I can with skimage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many functions in OpenCV have such limitations. OpenCV is written under the assumption you'll use it with a simple video camera that produces 8 bit images. For more precise work you're better off switching to a different library that is happy to work with floating-point images. In Python you have scikit-image, which is quite good, and DIPlib, which is way better (I'm an author, so quite biased!).

In scikit-image you have [two optical flow functions](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.registration.html): `skimage.registration.optical_flow_ilk` and `skimage.registration.optical_flow_tvl1`.

DIPlib does't have any built-in optical flow functions, but it's quite easy to construct them, because [it makes it easy to do linear algebra on pixels](https://diplib.org/diplib-docs/why_tensors.html). The classical Lucas-Kanade optical flow would be:

```py
img = ...  # your gray-scale floating-point image, with time as the 3rd dimension

gradient_sigma = 1.0
window_sigma = 5.0
A = dip.Gradient(img, gradient_sigma, process=[True, True, False]);
b = -dip.Derivative(img, [0, 0, 1], gradient_sigma);
ATA = dip.Gauss(A @ dip.Transpose(A), window_sigma);
ATb = dip.Gauss(A @ b, window_sigma);
v = dip.Inverse(ATA) @ ATb;
```

In this code, `img`, as a NumPy array, would have time as the first index, y as the second index, and x as the third index). You can construct it by putting the series of images into a list and converting that to an array.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer and I’d just like to let you know that I’m incredibly grateful for your response.